# No other account after changing username

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, display-names

I have changed my user name (from MByD to Binyamin Sharet), and pressed the **Copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts** and now, when I look at my profile, under accounts I see 0 accounts and the text **You have no other accounts on the Stack Exchange network**. Is it normal?

[image]

**Update**
After going to the **accounts** tab in the network profile, it got OK. So now I can't reproduce, but still...

Comment: I've gotta assume this just triggered the associations to rebuild for some reason, and... it took a few minutes.

Comment: @NineShogsShogging makes sense, but shouldn't it be triggered as I change it / Copying the profile?

Comment: Yeah, but processes that take a while tend to be queued up and processed outside of the normal page request process on SE. I can't say for sure this is one of those things, but I wouldn't doubt it - especially since it has to happen externally to any one site (the only site where it'd be appropriate to integrate would be stackexchange.com, which *may* be why you got your associations back after visiting that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a problem with a specific server supporting the stackauth backend (which hosts the accounts APIs internally) at the time you had this issue - it's been corrected now.

You see, every once in a while NY-WEB04 **LOSES ITS DAMN MIND** and can't see the freaking database server (NY-DB01 in this case), we don't know why.  However, this now being the second *major* incident of the exact same type means it warrants a lot more investigation, we'll be taking a hard look at NY-WEB04 this week.